# Python - Change kivy configuration at startup

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, kivy

I'm new to python.

I'm trying to develop a python app using Kivy and I would like to change some parameters in my virtual environment. Hence I've added a kivy.ini file to my project with my desired configuration.

```py
from kivy.config import Config
Config.read('kivy.ini')

from kivy.logger import Logger

import json

class SysmacUI(object):
    def __init__ (self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        Logger.info("SysmacApp: SysmacUI application starting...")
        self.start()
        self.stop()

    def start(self):
        Logger.info("SysmacApp: Connecting to gRPC server...")

    def stop(self):
        Logger.info("SysmacApp: Disconnecting from gRPC server...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SysmacUI().run()
```

But kivy.logger uses the initial configuration from the original config.ini file located in my user folder. And then change to the new log's location after purging the original log's folder.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Joan Magnet\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-09-26_24.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.6.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "F:\Projectes\Python\Sysmac\.venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.10 (tags/v3.9.10:f2f3f53, Jan 17 2022, 15:14:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "F:\Projectes\Python\Sysmac\.venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in F:\Projectes\Python\Sysmac\logs\kivy_23-09-26_8.txt
[INFO   ] [SysmacApp   ] SysmacUI application starting...
[INFO   ] [SysmacApp   ] Connecting to gRPC server...
[INFO   ] [SysmacApp   ] Disconnecting from gRPC server...
```

Is there a way that Kivy uses initially my kivy.ini configuration file so my logs folder can be purged and never generates a new log in my profile folder?